# How to count a word in a list by using lambda?

Tags: python

I have a text file like this: "My name is John. My profession is mechanic. My car's color is black..." After I convert this text file into a list, I want to search how many "is" there are in the text. To do that, I wrote that function but it is not working:

```
def count(word, my_list):
    print(functools.reduce(lambda x: "word" in x, my_list))
```

and I tried this

```
def count(word, my_list):
    result = sum(map(lambda x: "word" in x, my_list))
    print(result)
```

Both functions shows 0 instead of 3. I don't want to use loop.

Comment: replace "word" with "is".

Comment: Why are you doing this? what's wrong with `lst.count('is')`? or even `string.count('is')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking up the string `"word"` in your list instead of the `word` parameter you pass to you function. But using `reduce` isn't the right approach here because that would successively reduce the word list to a single value.

There are many ways to achieve word counting. One example would be using the built-in [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
from collections import Counter

text = "My name is John. My profession is mechanic. My car's color is black..."
word_count = Counter(text.split())
print(word_count['is'])
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you. It works for me but how can I do that using reduce function?

Comment: If you really wanted to, you could do `functools.reduce((lambda word_count, word: word_count + bool(word == 'is')), my_list, 0)` but that is hard to understand and hacky. It's important to use the right tool for the task at hand.

Comment: Good use of `collections.Counter`, so +1. However, it'd be better to first run `text.lower()` to make everything case-insensitive. If you don't do this, then "Is" and "is" will be counted as different words.

Comment: @MichaelM. fair point but then, you'd also count occurrences of "... Islamic State (IS) ..." :) so I'd say there's more complexity in that and it depends on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

Your second function is correct, but the mistake is you are searching the string "word" in each element of the list, that is why it is resulting 0.

Instead you can match the search word, while iterating through the list, like below.

```
def count(word, my_list):
result = sum(map(lambda x: x==word, my_list))
print(result)
```